# Getting autocomplete to pull from mysql db

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, autocomplete

I have a Country, State, City input field on my website and I am trying to build a autocomplete feature that will show the current options that are listed in the database. Here is  what I have, I can't get it to work at all and I am stuck at this point.

html

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form" method="get" name="form1" action="searchresults.php"                onsubmit="return checkRequired();">

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputPassword2">Country</label>
                        <input type="text" name="country"  class="form-control input-lg" id="country" style="font-size:15px;" placeholder="Country">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputPassword2">State</label>
                        <input type="text" name="state" class="form-control input-lg" id="state" style="font-size:15px;" placeholder="State">
                    </div>


                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail2">City</label>
                        <input type="text" name="city" class="form-control  input-lg" style="font-size:15px;" id="city" placeholder="City">
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search Photographers</button>
                    <input type="hidden" name="country_select" id="country_select" value="" />

                    <input type="hidden" name="state_select" id="state_select" value="" />

                </form>
```

javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

//autocomplete

$("#country").autocomplete({
    source: "search_country.php",
    minLength: 1,
    delay:10,
    select: function(event, ui) {
        $("#country_select").val(ui.item.value);
        $("#state").autocomplete(
            {
                source: "search_state.php?country=" + $('#country_select').val(),
                minLength: 1,
                    selectFirst: false
            }
            );  

         }
}); 





$("#state").autocomplete({
    source: "search_state.php?country=" + $('#country_select').val(),
    minLength: 1,
     delay:10,
    select: function(event, ui) {
        $("#state_select").val(ui.item.value);
        $("#city").autocomplete(
            {
                source: "search_city.php?state=" + $('#state_select').val(),
                minLength: 1,
                    selectFirst: false
            }
            );  

         }
}); 

$("#city").autocomplete(
{
    source: "search_city.php?state=" + $('#state_select').val(),
    minLength: 1,
    selectFirst: false
}
);  


});
```

search_country.php

```
<?php
require_once('includes/mysqli_connection.php');
if (isset($_GET['term'])){
    $return_arr = array();

    $query = "SELECT country FROM qls3_users where country like '%".$_GET['term']."%' group by country";
    $rs=mysqli_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
        if(mysqli_num_rows($rs)>0)
        {
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($rs))
            {   
                $return_arr[] =  $row['country'];
            }           
        }
/* Toss back results as json encoded array. */
   echo json_encode($return_arr);
}


?>
```

Comment: the checkRequired() function works perfect, I'm not asking about that so I didn't include that part of the code.

Comment: Could be his own function...

Comment: Whoa there cowboy, have you even gotten the first one working before you start firing off the others?!  Where are you defining `term` that you're looking for in your `PHP`?

Comment: sorry ignore that `term` question! Just checked the docs.

Comment: @RobSchmuecker Actually, the OP didn't state "what" wasn't working - *"I can't get it to work at all"*. I take *posted* code for face value, and I for one don't see a named element called `term`; so the SQL's execution is based on that conditional statement.

Comment: @Fred-ii- yes I see however that jQuery's `autocomplete` guns off a get request to `source` with parameter `term` http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source

Comment: @RobSchmuecker I tend to want and agree with that, yet when it comes to PHP and [**superglobals**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) along with forms, an `isset()` and a missing *form* named element, doesn't add up too well.

Comment: @Fred-ii- yep I quite agree :)

Comment: @RobSchmuecker I'm almost willing to bet my last dollar that if OP were to do `if(!isset($_GET['term'])){` that SQL would fire up, or adding error reporting such as `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`, would get an error thrown such as `Undefined index term...`

Comment: @Fred-ii- it also irks me somewhat when an OP asks a question and then seemingly goes home or off for a long lunch so when one's trying to help troubleshoot one's actually commenting to oneself!

Comment: calm down their Fred, I am a newbie and I'm trying to comprehend everything here.

Comment: @jonathon Err... I don't think you mean me ;) - or what comment did I put in?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I tried both those suggestions with no results.

Comment: @jonathon No errors thrown at all?

Comment: i put the error code on the php file and nothing

Comment: @jonathon yes I was commenting in general!  Try going directly to `whateveryourhostis/search_country.php?term=testcountry` in your browser and see what PHP returns.

Comment: It returned a blank white screen @RobSchmuecker

Comment: @jonathon it should be irrelevant that you are a newbie, however with that in mind I did ask you a question as to whether you even got the first `autocomplete` working before calling all the others in a chain and you didn't respond.  Hence I get irked that I'm giving my time to someone who *seemingly* has gone away!

Comment: I found an error here `mysql_error()` this should be `mysqli_error()`

Comment: @jonathon then it's definately at the very least a PHP issue.

Comment: Plus, is your DB connection file `mysqli_` or `mysql_` or PDO?

Comment: @Fred-ii- well spotted. jonathon, remedy that and then run the browser trick again.

Comment: fixed the mysqli_error(), didn't change anything

Comment: yes database connection is mysqli_

Comment: @RobSchmuecker the autocomplete function doesn't work at all on any of the input fields.

Comment: If your PHP isn't returning anything then they won't work.  PHP first needs to return an array (empty if needbe) and then JSON-encode that for the autocomplete to not bomb.

Comment: @Fred-ii- refreshed and tried the browser trick, nothing.

Comment: I take it that you have different files `search_country.php` and `search_state.php` and `search_city.php` to search with?

Comment: Ok, we've struck a blank here really.  First off, I would now suggest just echoeing *something* out at stages ideally a `print_r` of the various variables of your PHP and `exit()` ing to see where it's falling over.  It's a crappy way of debugging but it seems you're out of options.  There is obviously something wrong with your PHP setup or script.

Comment: that is correct @Fred-ii-

Comment: alright @RobSchmuecker I will play around with it and see what happens, thanks for the help guys and I will keep you posted on the results.

Comment: If as Rob said, in doing `/search_country.php?term=Australia` failed when going straight to PHP/SQL and it failed, then this would mean your query failed. I would try and use `$term=$_GET['term'];` then `WHERE country='$term'` see if that works in straight PHP/SQL.

Comment: @jonathon if other PHP scripts are working then it'll just be something with the DB and/or query, if you're really stuck we can chat on skype and maybe do a teamviewer quick.  It's probably something quick and simple.

Comment: alright so i put echo jonathon at the very bottom of the php file and did localhost/search_country.php?term=United States and it echoed jonathon

Comment: Well, now put it `in` the `if(isset(` and see if it *still* works and keep going like that until you end up jonathonless!

Comment: alright so it won't display it if I put it in the 'if(isset('

Comment: alright so i got some errors to come up: Notice: Undefined index: term in /Library/WebServer/Documents/search_country.php on line 10

Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in /Library/WebServer/Documents/search_country.php on line 11

Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in /Library/WebServer/Documents/search_country.php on line 11

Comment: I fixed two of the errors, now im getting this: Notice: Undefined index: term in /Library/WebServer/Documents/search_country.php on line 10
["United States"]

Comment: alright im narrowing it down so I took the ! out of if(isset($_GET['term'])){ and added $db_conx to mysqli_query and now the autocomplete for country works, but not for state and city.

Comment: Alright its fixed, i just needed to add the second variable to the mysqli_query. Thanks guys for the help!